# how to handle hyperlinked textarea in selenium

Tags: selenium, hyperlink, textarea

I have a page, where the link is defined with text area. How do I handle this to pass a value to it via selenium?

Here is the UI Code:

```
<a:TextArea name="Some Name">
```

I want to click on the link also wants to type the value into it. But with Selenium, I am not able to do that.

Can someone know how to do this?

Comment: can you add a screenshot of this field UI?

Comment: It is shown as hyperlink.

Comment: Your question is not clear, can you add a screen shot of UI along with clear description?

Comment: Basically, I want to know, can I pass a text using sendKeys/type at the backend, when I click on a link.

Comment: You mean, you clicked on link and it opens a text box to enter a value and in that text box you want to enter any text ?

Comment: Yes, you can using Jquery/javascript by disabling first clicking on link, second thing after the typing, you can still clcik on link

Answer (score 0):

Nice Question.

How about manipulating the DOM elements with javascript.

As you haven't provided the code so here is the descriptive answer to your question. You need to follow certain steps in order to achieve that.

1. Find Elements
2. Disable the link using Javascript, here you can stop its click event
3. Once you had disabled the click event, you can sendkeys to that field.
4. Once you done with sendKeys, You can undo the above changes and make click on field.(If You can't undo then just get the `href` attribute of the `<a>` tag and store it in any variable and once done with sendkeys, visit that link by passing the variable.

Do let me know if any query occurs.